# groupby(..).sum() of `inf` values resulting in `NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following `pandas.DataFrame`:

[image]

where the column `p_nom_max` contains `inf` values:

```
> df["p_nom_max"] == np.inf

Generator
DE0 1 nuclear     True
DE0 2 nuclear     True
DE0 3 nuclear    False
Name: p_nom_max, dtype: bool
```

When aggregating over this column using `.sum()` the result is as expected `inf`:

```
> df["p_nom_max"].sum()

inf
```

However when doing a `.groupby("carrier")` and then aggregating over `p_nom_max`, the standard functions result in `NaN` values, only a `lambda-wrapper` gives the correct result:

```
> df.groupby("carrier").agg({"p_nom_max": ["sum", np.sum, lambda x: np.sum(x)]})

p_nom_max
         sum    sum <lambda_0>
carrier
nuclear  NaN    NaN inf
```

Can someone help me understand what is going on here and why the standard groupby gives `NaN` instead of `inf` as a result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is bug already reported [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/50367#issuecomment-1381506488) and [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/53606), seems in new version it will working correctly.

Comment: Thanks, missed that. Yes, seems to be scheduled for `pandas=2.1`.